# OS X Keyboard Shortcut for Sublime Text 3 using System Preferences

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3

I'm trying to create a shortcut key binding in Sublime Text 3 on os x 10.15.6 using system preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts. I can't seem to figure out exactly what I'm missing or misspelling in my menu path. Here is a screenshot of the menu path:

[image]

The command I'm entering in system preferences is:

```
Tools SublimeREPL Python Python RUN - current file
```

Can't figure out what I'm missing. Do I need the arrows or is my dash wrong? I've put this off for a while and have never been able to figure this little thing out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You also need to fix your command name [I noticed after fixing it in the answer] `Python - RUN current file`

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Only put the last list item in the nested list. In this case that would mean you should set the command/shortcut name to `Python - RUN current file`. As long as this is the only menu bar item with this name then this will suffice.
2. If you have multiple menu bar commands with the same name then you must specify the full path of the command. You may also want to do this just to be careful or to prevent possible conflicts with newly added commands or changing menu items (such as Controls->Play Recent->*Song Name* on iTunes). You can specify the full path by putting an arrow (->) between levels in the command. For you this would be `Tools->SublimeREPL->Python->Python - RUN current file`.